# C++ error when building DLL: argument of type const wchar_t* is incompatible with parameter of type LPWSTR

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, lpwstr

I am a complete novice to C++ programming.

I need to create a DLL using header and solution files that were provided in a tutorial. I have followed basic steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=email) but, I am getting following errors in the solution file:

L111
`!CreateProcess(L".\\phreeqc\\phreeqc.exe",`

L112
`TEXT(".\\phreeqc\\phreeqc.exe .\\phreeqc\\phreeqc_input.txt .\\phreeqc\\phreeqc_input.out .\\phreeqc\\wateq4f_plus.dat")`

Errors:

L111

> C2664 'BOOL CreateProcessW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,BOOL,DWORD,LPVOID,LPCWSTR,LPSTARTUPINFLOW,LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const wchar_t[105]' to 'LPWSTR'

L112

> E0167 argument of type "const wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter
> of type "LPWSTR".

I understand that the specifics in the above lines of code will not mean much to many of you but I am hoping that someone can at least understand the C++ error and help out here.

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode version of `CreateProcess` (which is a macro that maps to `CreateProcessW`) requires a writable string for the `lpCommandLine` parameter, and string literals are `const`.  You therefore cannot pass a string literal directly for this parameter.

Instead, you can change your code like so:

```
WCHAR lpCommandLine [] = L"...";
BOOL ok = CreateProcess (L"your_application_name_here", lpCommandLine, ...);
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)